# How to specify database of OCI_CONNECT

Tags: php, oracle

Goog afternoon.

I'm trying to implement a conection with Oracle Database from PHP.
But i'm not getting success.

```
$conn_oracle = oci_connect('username', 'password', '10.1.11.7');
```

Please, witch the order of parameters?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php - is there something specific you don't understand from the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Check "Oracle Database Name Connection Identifiers" on page 104 of the free [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/php/201212-ug-php-oracle-1884760.pdf) PDF.

Commonly you probably need just the service name of the database that is running on your computer. If that name was `XEPDB1`, then your PHP code would then use

```
$conn_oracle = oci_connect('username', 'password', '10.1.11.7/XEPDB1');
```

If the database service is running on a non-default port, you might to include that:

```
$conn_oracle = oci_connect('username', 'password', '10.1.11.7:1522/XEPDB1');
```

(The default port is 1521).

Typically to find a service name you could (i) ask someone else using the DB (ii) look at other connection strings you use in other tools (iii) ask the DBA (iv) log into a terminal where the DB is running, set the Oracle environment (on Linux etc with `source /usr/local/bin/oraenv`), and then run `lsnrctl status` (v) trying common names: `XEPDB1`, `orclpdb`, or `orclpdb1`.